# How to combine the data from many data frames into a single data frame with an array as the data values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

If I have many panda data frames, with the same index structure, I want to create a data frame with the same index structure but the data values are np.arrays (actually I want np.matrix.)

Merging seems to do just fine with simple operations df1 + df2 adds element wise but np.array((df1,df2)) doesn't do at all what I want.

Does pandas have a method of doing this without rebuilding the entire object element by element?

E.g. if I have

```
df1 =       col1    col2
      1        1       2
      2        3       4
df2 =       col1    col2
      1        5       6
      2        7       8
```

and want

```
df2 =       col1    col2
      1    [1,5]   [2,6]
      2    [3,7]   [4,8]
```

Comment: Have you considered using a Panel or a MultiIndex?

Comment: I have, but I supposed I have the same issue. I need the data elements as arrays, because i want to do linear algebra operations on them. So even if I used a Panel or a MultiIndexed data frame the data elements still need to be arrays. 

So is there a way of building arrays as elements from Panels or MultiIndex objects that is easier?

Comment: You can lookup the `.values` in a Panel which are stored as numpy arrays (you may want to tweak it for contiguous-ness)... example of a linalg function you have in mind?

Comment: Oh hmm, I guess I need to look closer at Panel. I plan on doing things like making the arrays matrices and computing eigen values.

Comment: Oh, `.values` does not do what I want. If I make a Panel out of two data frames, `.values` gives me two arrays which are the data out of each data frame. I need a array which is data from the same entry from each different data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Panel structure to do this:

```
In [11]: p = pd.Panel({'df1': df1, 'df2': df2})

In [12]: p['df1']
Out[12]:
   col1  col2
1     1     2
2     3     4
```

And you can do an apply over the major axis:

```
In [13]: p.apply(np.sum, axis='major')  # use linalg function here instead of np.sum
Out[13]:
      df1  df2
col1    4   12
col2    6   14
```

*Note: for each (df, col) pair, you are applying over a numpy array:*

```
In [21]: def f(x):
              print(repr(x))
              return 1

In [22]: p.apply(f, 'major')
array([1, 3])
array([2, 4])
array([5, 7])
array([6, 8])
Out[22]:
      df1  df2
col1    1    1
col2    1    1
```

*You could select another numpy/linalg function (or create your own).*

Update: actually this isn't quite what you want, you have to use the items axis:

```
In [31]: p.apply(f, 'items')
array([1, 5])
array([2, 6])
array([3, 7])
array([4, 8])
Out[31]:
   col1  col2
1     1     1
2     1     1
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like this lets me store it the way I want, but it does let me access the data in a way which may let me do what I need. I clearly had not looked close enough at Panels. I will have to look into how apply more carefully, I don't understand why you would have the function return 1. Thanks though!

Comment: @f4hy I was just returning 1 to give a trivial example which printed the reprs. You could create your own function and return something interesting, which would be applied to `array([1, 5])` etc.

Comment: Hmm, well trying it out doesn't quite seem to do what I want. The return value needs to be of length of the panel, where if I want to operate on the whole array to compute a single object it won't let me return that. Apply doesn't let me reduce the panel. For example as a test I wanted to apply `np.reshape(x,(2,2))` on a panel of 4 dfs and it fails. I guess I need to do all my work within the apply, and flatten it back out. This has me on the right track now I think so thanks again.